# MYSQL Replace part of a space delimited string

Tags: mysql, regex, string

Is it possible to replace part of a space delimited string using the replace function?

e.g. If i have the following string '123456 456 789' and wanted to replace the second occurrence of '456' with 'XXXXX'.

I have tried using the following:

```
UPDATE table 
set column = REPLACE(column,'456','xxxxx')
Where.......
```

The issue being that it will replace the first occurrence of '456' as well. I am unable to just change the pattern in the replace statement to ' 456 ' as the '456' may appear at the beginning or end of the cell. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Using MySQL for this one

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to do this:

```
set column = REGEXP_REPLACE(column,'[[:<:]]456[[:>:]]','xxxxx')
```

The regex syntax add words delimiter `[[:<:]]`and `[[:>:]]` (matches at start and end of the string and between regex *words* `\w` and "not words" `\W`).

*NB*: the regex is syntactically and logically correct but the above code is untested

Answer (score 0):

USE MySQL REPLACE,SUBSTR or LOCATE

```
REPLACE('123456 456 789',
SUBSTR('123456 456 789',
LOCATE(' ','123456 456 789'),
LOCATE(' ','123456 456 789',
LOCATE(' ','123456 456 789')+1)-LOCATE(' ','123456 456 789')),' xxxxx')
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/33141)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ',
SUBSTRING_INDEX( '123456 456 789', ' ', 1),
'xxxx',
SUBSTRING_INDEX( '123456 456 789', ' ', -1))
```

As in MySql reference manual:

> SUBSTRING_INDEX Return a substring from a string before the specified
>   number of occurrences of the delimiter

Have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

If You use a negative index it starts from the end of the string

CONCAT_WS Return concatenate with separator. So:

> '123456'+' '+'xxxx'+' '+'789'

If you want to test try:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',
SUBSTRING_INDEX( '123456 456 789', ' ', 1),
'xxxx',
SUBSTRING_INDEX( '123456 456 789', ' ', -1));

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( '123456 456 789', ' ', 1);

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( '123456 456 789', ' ', -1);
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code does and why it is supposed to work?